# Como fazer efeito em "cascata" com Javascript / jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css3

Imaginem que eu tenha uma lista de 20 blocos `<li>`, e que quando a página carregar, cada um deles deva ser mostrado com diferença de milissegundos de um para o outro (isso seria realizado com `CSS3`, portanto o código só teria que adicionar uma classe nos elementos), como que um efeito "cascata".

Como eu conseguiria passar essa lógica para JavaScript / jQuery?

Aqui está um [**`FIDDLE`**](http://jsfiddle.net/N2hD5/) com todo o exemplo, só faltando a lógica do efeito "cascata".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pode usar assim:

```
$('ul li').each(function (i, el) { // percorrer cada elemento
    setTimeout(function () {   
        $(el).addClass('on');  // adicionar a classe
    }, i * 200);               // usar o indice do .each() do jQuery para multiplicar por 200 milisegundos
});
```

### [Exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/CMZf6/1/)

Comment: +1 Ao contrário da minha resposta, essa não depende da criação de variáveis extra desnecessariamente

Comment: @mgibsonbr, desta vez concordo contigo, costumas ser tu a ter a melhor e mais rápida resposta :)

Answer (score 5):

> Para uma solução melhor e mais concisa, ver [a resposta do @Sergio](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/11956/215).

Eu usaria um simples `setInterval`:

```
var indice = 0;
var interval = setInterval(function() {
    var proximo = $("li").eq(indice++);
    if ( proximo.length == 0 )
        clearInterval(interval);
    else
        proximo.addClass("on");
}, 500);
```

[Exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/N2hD5/1/).

Comment: Ambas as perguntas (a sua e a do @Sergio) funcionaram corretamente e foram de fácil entendimento, o que me deixou na dúvida de qual escolher. Achei que um critério justo para o "desempate" seria por o desempenho do código a prova, e foi o que fiz. O seu código mostrou ter melhor desempenho e por isto vou marcar a sua como correta, mas a do Sergio também é eficiente e até menor. Link do teste: http://jsperf.com/efeito-em-cascata

Comment: @Kazzkiq Valeu, mas há um problema fundamental no seu teste: na minha solução, o código para cada elemento só executa na hora de processar aquele elemento de fato; na do Sergio, o loop para processar toda a lista é executado de uma vez só. Ou seja, está comparando maçãs com laranjas. Tentei adaptar o teste pra ficar mais justo, mas é difícil, já que se trata de eventos assíncronos. Mas tenho fortes suspeitas que o dele é mais eficiente também - já que o meu usa `eq`.

Comment: P.S. Desisto! É impossível avaliar corretamente a performance dessas soluções usando jsperf... Por favor **não executem** a Revisão 3 do link acima (criada por mim), pois vai travar seu browser! :(